# How Predicates and Domain Of Discourse are related in First Order Logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic

I am new to Mathematical logic and I am unable to understand the relationship between Predicates and Domain of discourse in First-order logic. Particularly, the following questions are coming to my mind:

1. Can we define any number of distinct predicates over a single domain of discourse?
   For example, say domain of discourse is "**Set of all Human Beings**", then can we make a First-order logic statement based on the following English sentence:

   $Some\:people\:are\:Engineers,\:some\:people\:are\:Doctors\:and\:some\:people\: are\:Musicians.$

The above statement seems to have three predicates based on the same domain of discourse. Is that correct?

2. Also, can a First-Order Logic Statement have more than one domain of discourse?
   For Example, The Quantified Version of The statement: "**Every King has at least one Minister**", seems to have two domain of discourses: **Set of all Kings** and **Set of all Ministers**. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

The *domain* $D$ of an interpretation $\mathscr I$ is a collection of objects (e.g. numbers) over which variables range.

A predicate symbol $P$ of the language is interpreted with a subset of the domain, if $P$ is a *unary* predicate symbol, i.e. $P^{\mathscr I} \subseteq D$, with a binary relation on the domain $D$, if $P$ is a *binary* predicate symbol, i.e. $P^{\mathscr I} \subseteq D\times D$, and so on.

Having said that, if $H$ is the domain of Human beings, then the three (unary) predicates $E, D$ and $M$ will be interpreted with subsets of $H$, i.e. with the subset of Humans that are Engineers, Doctors and Musicians respectively.

Regarding the second question, we may have domains partitioned into disjoint subdomains (see [many-sorted predicate logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-sorted_logic)), but your example does not need that; it is enough to use two predicates $K$ amd $M$ denoting Kings and Ministers respectively, in the domain of Humans.